# Chain Scala Futures when processing a Seq of objects?

Tags: scala, sequence, traversal

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.Future._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object TestClass {

  final case class Record(id: String)

  final case class RecordDetail(id: String)

  final case class UploadResult(result: String)

  val ids: Seq[String] = Seq("a", "b", "c", "d")

  def fetch(id: String): Future[Option[Record]] = Future {
    Thread sleep 100
    if (id != "b" && id != "d") {
      Some(Record(id))
    } else None
  }

  def fetchRecordDetail(record: Record): Future[RecordDetail] = Future {
    Thread sleep 100
    RecordDetail(record.id + "_detail")
  }

  def upload(recordDetail: RecordDetail): Future[UploadResult] = Future {
    Thread sleep 100
    UploadResult(recordDetail.id + "_uploaded")
  }

  def notifyUploaded(results: Seq[UploadResult]): Unit = println("notified " + results)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //for each id from ids, call fetch method and if record exists call fetchRecordDetail 
    //and after that upload RecordDetail, collect all UploadResults into seq
    //and call notifyUploaded with that seq and await result, you should see "notified ...." in console


    // In the following line of code how do I pass result of fetch to fetchRecordDetail function
    val result = Future.traverse(ids)(x => Future(fetch(x)))
    // val result: Future[Unit] = ???

    Await.ready(result, Duration.Inf)
  }

}
```

My problem is that I don't know what code to put in the `main` to make it work as written in the comments. To sum up, I have an `ids:Seq[String]` and I want each id  to go through asynchronous methods `fetch`, `fetchRecordDetail`, `upload`, and finally the whole `Seq` to come to `notifyUploaded`.

Comment: please add more description

Comment: pls go through the code you will find the description. I want to complete the following part--------> val result: Future[Unit] = ???

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the simplest way to do it is :

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //for each id from ids, call fetch method and if record exists call fetchRecordDetail
    //and after that upload RecordDetail, collect all UploadResults into seq
    //and call notifyUploaded with that seq and await result, you should see "notified ...." in console

    def runWithOption[A, B](f: A => Future[B], oa: Option[A]): Future[Option[B]] = oa match {
      case Some(a) => f(a).map(b => Some(b))
      case None => Future.successful(None)
    }

    val ids: Seq[String] = Seq("a", "b", "c", "d")

    val resultSeq: Seq[Future[Option[UploadResult]]] = ids.map(id => {
      for (or: Option[Record] <- fetch(id);
           ord: Option[RecordDetail] <- runWithOption(fetchRecordDetail, or);
           our: Option[UploadResult] <- runWithOption(upload, ord)
      ) yield our
    })

    val filteredResult: Future[Seq[UploadResult]] = Future.sequence(resultSeq).map(s => s.collect({ case Some(ur) => ur }))
    val result: Future[Seq[UploadResult]] = filteredResult.andThen({ case Success(s) => notifyUploaded(s) })

    Await.ready(result, Duration.Inf)
  }
```

The idea is that you first get a `Seq[Future[_]]` that you `map` through all the methods (here it is done using for-comprehension). Here is an important trick is to actually pass `Seq[Future[Option[_]]]`. Passing `Option[_]` through the whole chain via `runWithOption` helper method simplifies code a lot without a need to block until the very last stage.

Then you convert `Seq[Future[_]]` into a `Future[Seq[_]]` and filter out results for those `ids` that failed at the `fetch` stage. And finally you apply `notifyUploaded`.

P.S. Note that there is no error handling in this code whatsoever and it is not clear how you expect it to behave in case of errors at different stages.